# Connect spark to Cassandra3

Tags: python, apache-spark, cassandra

I have a cassandra3 cluster and I decided to use spark1.6 (prebuild with hadoop2.6) to analyze stored data.
I want to implement some functionalities with python. In order to do this, first I ran following command:

```
./bin/spark-submit examples/src/main/python/cassandra_inputformat.py 192.168.100.251 test-keyspace test-table
```

With this command, I ran into 
`java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.cassandra.hadoop.cql3.CqlPagingInputFormat`.

To solve this, I ran:

```
./bin/spark-submit --jars lib/spark-examples-1.6.0-hadoop2.6.0.jar examples/src/main/python/cassandra_inputformat.py 192.168.100.251 test-keyspace test-table
```

Then I got to the error `java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: Found interface org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobContext, but class was expected`.

After a little bit of searching, I got that the error is because hadoop1 jars are available with examples but hadoop2 is required to run them!

So, I tried these solutions:

1. I tried to use spark2.6 prebuild hadoop1 version, That get me to the problem that hadoop1 is not compatible with cassandra3.

   ```
   py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling z:org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.newAPIHadoopRDD.
   : org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 0.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 0, localhost): java.lang.RuntimeException: InvalidRequestException(why:unconfigured table schema_columnfamilies)
   ```
2. I tried to use [spark-cassandra-connector](https://github.com/datastax/spark-cassandra-connector), that still leads me to not being compatible with cassandra3 with error similiar to the above error saying table schema_columnfamilies is not configured.